# Yii, attaching a javascript function on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, yii, submit

I want to attach a function to my submit button. But my code doesn't seem to be calling the function.

Basically what I want it to do is, enabling **all** disabled field when the form is being submitted.

This below is my code:

```
<script>
function enableField() {
    $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
}
</script>


<?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'));
    $this->endWidget();
?>
```

This `#Booking_clientPackagedService_id` initially is disabled after certain action being done. But when I click on submit, I would like to enable the field. How can I do it? Please advise, thanks! :D

**EDIT**

So I've removed `onclick` event on my submit button and added as per Kancho Iliev's comment.

```
$( "#booking-form" ).submit(function() {
  $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

But it is still not working. Where have I missed out?

Answer (score 2):

Remove onclick event, and add

```
$("your_form_name").submit(function(){
   enableField();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of attaching a submit function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#formName").submit(function() {
        alert("hi");
        //do whatever 
    });
});
```